# C++ Adding 2 arrays together quickly

Tags: c++, performance, arrays, micro-optimization, simd

Given the arrays:

```
int canvas[10][10];
int addon[10][10];
```

Where all the values range from 0 - 100, **what is the fastest way in C++ to add those two arrays so each cell in canvas equals itself plus the corresponding cell value in addon?**

IE, I want to achieve something like:

```
canvas += another;
```

So if canvas[0][0] =3 and addon[0][0] = 2 then canvas[0][0] = 5

Speed is essential here as I am writing a very simple program to brute force a knapsack type problem and there will be tens of millions of combinations.

And as a small extra question (thanks if you can help!) **what would be the fastest way of checking if any of the values in canvas exceed 100?**  Loops are slow!

Comment: Sorry I am only good enough to build this solution as a console application.

Comment: Why are you bruteforcing the knapsack problem? There's a faster dynamic programming solution. Usually it's better to improve the algorithm than to use code hacks.

Comment: How vital is the extra speed? If it is getting to be a combinatorially large problem you may want to consider parallelizing the code. Also are you specifically wanting to brute force the problem? If not I'd suggest looking into mixed integer programming and the branch and bound algorithm.

Comment: Are you looking for a straight C/C++ answer?  if you're willing to drop to something architecture-specific I'd look to see if there are  SIMD-style instructions (like SSE) that can help parallelize the operations (not that I have any idea exactly how that would work).

Comment: Speed is fairly vital, without any heuristics we are looking at anywhere from a few hundred million to up to 10 billion possible solutions I think.  The only calculations required for now are adding arrays together then calculating if any of the values exceed 100.

It's a packing/knapsack problem so the only way to guarantee optimum solution is brute force, and I am required to find the optimum solution each time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm really not very good at C++ but I can write programs like this fairly well, I wrote a simliar one which was very sucessful a few years ago for brute forcing poker hand statistics which was one of the fastest in the world, but I'm affraid in this instance I don't know what a lot of these terms (SIMD/Parallizing/SSE) mean :(

I was just hoping for a simple memory block addition instruction or something.

Comment: @Tom Gullen - I think you should post the exact problem and algorithm you're using right now. Finding the optimum solution does not require brute force for most knapsack problems, and even if it does, brute force algorithms can also be optimized. You can't really get much faster than loops and conditionals, but you can improve the algorithm.

Comment: @IVlad: It's actually a packing problem, where you have a 2 dimensional space represented with a canvas object, the you have shapes, represented with other arrays.  For example a square would be 

100 100 0 0 0
100 100 0 0 0
0   0   0 0 0

Or a triangle:

100 100 0.5
100 0.5 0
0.5 0   0

I need to go through every combination of shape rotation and placement to find the most compact solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an SSE4 implementation that should perform pretty well on Nehalem (Core i7):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

static inline int canvas_add(int canvas[10][10], int addon[10][10])
{
    __m128i * cp = (__m128i *)&canvas[0][0];
    const __m128i * ap = (__m128i *)&addon[0][0];
    const __m128i vlimit = _mm_set1_epi32(100);
    __m128i vmax = _mm_set1_epi32(INT_MIN);
    __m128i vcmp;
    int cmp;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10 * 10; i += 4)
    {
        __m128i vc = _mm_loadu_si128(cp);
        __m128i va = _mm_loadu_si128(ap);

        vc = _mm_add_epi32(vc, va);
        vmax = _mm_max_epi32(vmax, vc);   // SSE4 *

        _mm_storeu_si128(cp, vc);

        cp++;
        ap++;
    }
    vcmp = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(vmax, vlimit); // SSE4 *
    cmp = _mm_testz_si128(vcmp, vcmp);    // SSE4 *
    return cmp == 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -msse4.1 ...` or equivalent for your particular development environment.

For older CPUs without SSE4 (and with much more expensive misaligned loads/stores) you'll need to (a) use a suitable combination of SSE2/SSE3 intrinsics to replace the SSE4 operations (marked with an `*` above) and ideally (b) make sure your data is 16-byte aligned and use aligned loads/stores (`_mm_load_si128`/`_mm_store_si128`) in place of `_mm_loadu_si128`/`_mm_storeu_si128`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do anything faster than loops in just C++. You would need to use some platform specific vector instructions. That is, you would need to go down to the assembly language level. However, there are some C++ libraries that try to do this for you, so you can write at a high level and have the library take care of doing the low level [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) work that is appropriate for whatever architecture you are targetting with your compiler.

[MacSTL](http://www.pixelglow.com/macstl/) is a library that you might want to look at. It was originally a Macintosh specific library, but it is cross platform now. See their home page for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, with my other optimisation problem I found that if you know the array sizes, 'manually' coding in the additions:

a[0] = a[0] + b[0];
a[1] = a[1] + b[1];
....
a[20] = a[20] + b[20];

Is significantly faster than using loops when going through huge solution sets.

Comment: @Tom:  For small array sizes, that's almost certainly true.  If you make them too large, you may run into cache miss problems.

Comment: @Tom: Given the approriate flags the compiler might also be able to automatically unroll the loop to something like that, which makes for much cleaner code without sacrificing performance.

Answer (score 3):

The best you're going to do in standard C or C++ is to recast that as a one-dimensional array of 100 numbers and add them in a loop.  (Single subscripts will use a bit less processing than double ones, unless the compiler can optimize it out.  The only way you're going to know how much of an effect there is, if there is one, is to test.)

You could certainly create a class where the addition would be one simple C++ instruction (`canvas += addon;`), but that wouldn't speed anything up.  All that would happen is that the simple C++ instruction would expand into the loop above.

You would need to get into lower-level processing in order to speed that up.  There are additional instructions on many modern CPUs to do such processing that you might be able to use.  You might be able to run something like this on a GPU using something like [Cuda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).  You could try making the operation parallel and running on several cores, but on such a small instance you'll have to know how caching works on your CPU.

The alternatives are to improve your algorithm (on a knapsack-type problem, you might be able to use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in some way - without more information from you, we can't tell you), or to accept the performance.  Tens of millions of operations on a 10 by 10 array turn into hundreds of billions of operations on numbers, and that's not as intimidating as it used to be.  Of course, I don't know your usage scenario or performance requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Two parts: first, consider your two-dimensional array [10][10] as a single array [100]. The layout rules of C++ should allow this. Second, check your compiler for intrinsic functions implementing some form of [SIMD instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD), such as Intel's SSE. For example [Microsoft supplies a set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dh78ez(VS.71).aspx). I believe SSE has some instructions for checking against a maximum value, and even clamping to the maximum if you want.

Comment: @Tom Gullen, the best way to thank someone is to click on the up-arrow above the number next to the answer.

Comment: It wont let me because I'm new but I would sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative.

If you are 100% certain that all your values are between 0 and 100, you could change your type from an int to a uint8_t.  Then, you could add 4 elements together at once of them together using uint32_t without worrying about overflow.

That is ...

```
uint8_t  array1[10][10];
uint8_t  array2[10][10];
uint8_t  dest[10][10];
uint32_t *pArr1 = (uint32_t *) &array1[0][0];
uint32_t *pArr2 = (uint32_t *) &array2[0][0];
uint32_t *pDest = (uint32_t *) &dest[0][0];

int  i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof (dest) / sizeof (uint32_t); i++) {
    pDest[i] = pArr1[i] + pArr2[i];
}
```

It may not be the most elegant, but it could help keep you from going to architecture specific code.  Additionally, if you were to do this, I would strongly recommend you comment what you are doing and why.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out CUDA.  This kind of problem is *right* up CUDA's street.  Recommend the [Programming Massively Parallel Processors](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Massively-Parallel-Processors-Hands/dp/0123814723/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1281787175&sr=8-2) book.

However, this does require CUDA capable hardware, and CUDA takes a bit of effort to get setup in your development environment, so it would depend how important this really is!

Good luck!